# Why did the June 2016 SpaceX launch run out of propellant?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, fuel, landing, failure

In other words, what caused SpaceX to miscalculate the amount of propellant required to safely land the booster. They had landed successfully on the drone ship in April. So what went wrong here? What was different?

Comment: If this is the mishap I'm thinking of, they miscalculated how much TEA-TEB the rocket would need to restart the engines during reentry and landing.  There was enough propellant, but not enough of this pyrophoric chemical they use to start the engines.  Not making this an answer because my memory is so bad that this might be entirely made up.

Comment: It seems to be that they actually ran out of propellant https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/rockets/a21389/spacexs-rocket-landing-attempt-ran-out-of-fuel/ @WayneConrad

Comment: I'm glad I added that disclaimer then.

Comment: "liquid oxygen fuel", ugh

Comment: I do also recall a failure when they ran out of TEATEB, but thats something different @WayneConrad

Comment: I don't know enough about this to write an answer, but some sources say one of the engines had low performance and that's why it ran out of oxidizer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble "liquid oxygen fuel" is a special kind of LOX that you have to use with "RP1 oxidizer".

Answer (score 1):

When performing a propulsive landing, the harder you accelerate, the less speed you pick up from gravity, and the less fuel you need.

Falcon 9 flight 26 was intended to perform a three-engine landing burn.
According to an [Elon Musk tweet](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/743097337782763521), one of the engines wasn't operating at the intended power level.  This reduced the acceleration and increased the fuel needed: although the booster had enough fuel to perform a three-engine landing, it didn't have enough for a two-and-a-half-engine landing.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, "fuel" translates as "things that make the engines run".

Comment: Ah, so fuel is also "electricity". Got it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, for something like Rocket Lab's Electron rockets, yes.  I'm fairly sure that the Falcon 9 uses a gas-generator turbopump instead.

Comment: I'd be amazed if Merlins and Raptors don't require electrical power for sensors, controllers, etc.

Comment: Your Elon Musk tweet is from a day before [the one that says it ran out of oxygen](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/743602894226653184).  I think his opinions changed as SpaceX investigated the crash.

Comment: I dont think Mark actually cares about the distinction and is using fuel colloquially.  Which I think is fine.

Comment: I, for one, find the pedantry and associated refusal to accommodate very entertaining.